# Javascript inheritance .call .create and constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm relatively new at Javascript and I'm confused at the process of Inheritance. 
Here in this code snippet I got from a phaser tutorial, Bullet inherits from sprite. First it uses the call method which from my knowledge takes the properties from one method and inserts it into another. So at this point Bullet is given all the properties of Sprite. Call should take an object and then parameters of the object being called, so I understand why it's passing game and key but where does the 0,0  come from?

Okay but then after all that it does Bullet.prototype = Object.create to create the sprite object into the bullet prototype? But didn't it already do that with the call method?

and then it goes prototype.constructor = bullet but why would you need to do that when bullet already holds bullet?

If someone could explain this to me I would be very appreciative. Thank you!

```
var Bullet = function (game, key) {

    Phaser.Sprite.call(this, game, 0, 0, key);

    this.texture.baseTexture.scaleMode = PIXI.scaleModes.NEAREST;

    this.anchor.set(0.5);

    this.checkWorldBounds = true;
    this.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    this.exists = false;

    this.tracking = false;
    this.scaleSpeed = 0;

};

 Bullet.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
 Bullet.prototype.constructor = Bullet;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had a good link for you. But anyway...

All constructor functions have a prototype property initialized when the function was created as an object with a `constructor` property set the the constructor function itself. Both the function's `prototype` and the prototype's `constructor` properties are read-write and can be updated.

Objects created using a constructor function inherit properties from the object value held in the constructor function's `prototype` property *at the time the object was created*. This prototype object can in turn inherit properties from the prototype property of its own constructor, so setting up an inheritance chain.

`Object.create` is a factory function which returns a new object which inherits from an  object passed as the first parameter. The object returned will inherit its constructor property from the object provided to `Object.create` either directly if it's a local property, or indirectly from the object's prototype chain.

---

1. Calling `Phaser.Sprite` on a new Bullet object only adds local properties created by the `Phaser.Sprite` constructor.
2. `Bullet.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);` creates an object which inherits directly from `Phaser.Sprit.prototype`. `Bullet` objects will now indirectly inherit all Sprite's prototyped values via the inerhitance chain of Bullet objects.
3. `Bullet.prototype.constructor = Bullet;` creates a local `constructor` property on `Bullet.prototype` which is inherited by Bullet objects. Without this step they would inherit the property value `Sprite` via the inheritance chain.